# Concatenate a List<string> to end of array in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, list, csv, concatenation

**I have this code:**

```
public class Test3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    answers.add("Yes");
    answers.add("No");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://new.csv"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                String[] sae = line.split(",");
                sae = Arrays.copyOf(sae, sae.length + 1);
                sae[sae.length - 1] = answers.get(i);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sae));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}
**The output is:**

```
["something", "hello", Yes]
["something", "hello", No]
["abc", "bye", Yes]
["abc", "bye", No]
```

I'm reading a csv file and splitting it. I am concatenating a `list<string>` through for loop but I'm getting the `list<string>` at the end two times. How can I prevent it from doing it ?

**The output I want is:**

```
["something", "hello", Yes]
["abc", "bye", No]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a counter and increment it every time you read a line and:

- if the lines in your csv match those in answers:

  sae[sae.length - 1] = answers.get(counter);
- otherwise you may want to start again from the beginning:

  sae[sae.length - 1] = answers.get(counter % answers.size());

remove your for-loop, you don't need it

Comment: Thankyou. Sorry I didn't had the idea

Comment: Is there any way i can skip the first line of csv because it contain the headers ?

Comment: sure.. add br.readLine() before your while

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the whole `answers` array for every line in the `.csv` file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    answers.add("Yes");
    answers.add("No");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("new.csv"))) {
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] sae = line.split(",");
            sae = Arrays.copyOf(sae, sae.length + 1);
            sae[sae.length - 1] = answers.get(i%answers.size());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sae));
        }
    }
}
```

Lukas Resch mentioned a good answer, here's the code for it.